# Dependency Injection on a class instantiation of a sealed class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, sealed

I'm currently trying to build a sealed class that gets the configuration of the azure storage via settings stored in a JSON. I register the settings in the startup.cs class, and then inject it to the constructor. The problem is when I need to initiate the same class within the class because its a sealed class

```
public sealed class AzureFileStorage
{
    private static volatile AzureFileStorage instance;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();
    private readonly AzureBlobSettings _azureBlobSettings;

    public CloudStorageAccount StorageAccount { get; private set; }
    public CloudBlobClient BlobClient { get; private set; }
    public CloudBlobContainer Container { get; private set; }

    public AzureFileStorage(IOptions<AzureBlobSettings> fbAuthSettingsAccessor)
    {
        _azureBlobSettings = fbAuthSettingsAccessor.Value;
        StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_azureBlobSettings.BlobStorageConnectionString);

        //instantiate the client
        BlobClient = StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        //set the container
        Container = BlobClient.GetContainerReference(_azureBlobSettings.ContainerBlobAzureId);

    }

    public static AzureFileStorage Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {

                    if (instance == null)
                        instance = new AzureFileStorage(????);
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I initiaze azurefilestorage, if the azureblobsettings are being passed via dependency injection.

Comment: Why are you creating a static instance if you are using a dependency injection container? The standard way to handle this would to declare the type as a singleton in the container.

Comment: *“The problem is when I need to initiate the same class within the class because its a sealed class”* – You seem to be confusing **sealed** with **static** there. These are two completely unrelated concepts.

Answer (score 0):

As already alluded to by a commenter, the current design does not lend itself well to dependency injection.

The `AzureFileStorage` class should be refactored to remove the singleton instance and additionally having it's own abstraction.

```
public interface IAzureFileStorage {
    CloudStorageAccount StorageAccount { get; }
    CloudBlobClient BlobClient { get; }
    CloudBlobContainer Container { get; }
}

public sealed class AzureFileStorage : IAzureFileStorage {
    private readonly AzureBlobSettings _azureBlobSettings;


    public AzureFileStorage(IOptions<AzureBlobSettings> fbAuthSettingsAccessor) {
        _azureBlobSettings = fbAuthSettingsAccessor.Value;
        StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_azureBlobSettings.BlobStorageConnectionString);

        //instantiate the client
        BlobClient = StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        //set the container
        Container = BlobClient.GetContainerReference(_azureBlobSettings.ContainerBlobAzureId);
    }

    public CloudStorageAccount StorageAccount { get; private set; }
    public CloudBlobClient BlobClient { get; private set; }
    public CloudBlobContainer Container { get; private set; }
}
```

And registered as a singleton with the service collection

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    //...

    service.AddSingleton<IAzureFileStorage, AzureFileStorage>();

    //...
}
```

So that where ever `IAzureFileStorage` is explicitly injected,

```
private readonly IAzureFileStorage fileStore;

public SomeClass(IAzureFileStorage fileStore) {
    this.fileStore = fileStore;
}
```

the same instance will be used through out the application.